# MS Teams Installation Error in ubuntu 18.04 with dpkg

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

How to install the Ms Teams in Ubuntu 18.04, please guide.

Comment: SO is for programming questions only. Please ask on [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this guide:

https://pureinfotech.com/install-microsoft-teams-linux/

once you do `sudo dpkg -i teams.deb` you can run:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

which will resolve any dependencies or errors.

Answer (score 0):

first, open the terminal write,

> sudo apt update

then write

> sudo apt install snapd

at the end you write

> sudo snap install teams-for-linux

Comment: I would personally avoid snapd as an additional dependency.